# Drupal 8 - Weird behaviour with parameters

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have a form that accepts one input and after submits redirects to a controller that does some search stuff with solr.

I have discovered some weird behavior when certain words are used as a search term for the parameters of the route:

This is the SearchBoxForm form when the form is submitted, as you see it just redirects to the search controller
[image]

This is the controller action that accepts the redirect:
[image]

This is the route file:
[image]

So as you can see, the url can be as `domain.com/search` to `domain/search/term/tab/page/filter`.

No the problem, certain search words causes drupal to not properly load all js, some words are:
"**cache**", "**chemistry**" but other words work just fine like "**student**" or "**economy**".

The page works fine if you hit it with default parameters, ie `domain.com/search`
But `domain.com/search/cache` or `domain.com/search/cache/all/1/undefined` will not load js in any way.

Has anyone seen this problem before, or see something obvious that I have missed? I really hope this is not the render array or something that somehow sees cache in the parameters and thinks it something else..

Comment: I'm allways unsure about D8 cache :D I'd make a fast check adding $searchPage['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0] to see what happend.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to add which versions of Solr, Search API, Search API Solr, Drupal, etc ... you are using as the functionality varies quite depending on those.